# Converting a list of lists into its sub-lists using a for loop and .format

Tags: python, list, for-loop, string.format

I would like to apply this idea to separate a list of lists into individually named list. Say `L = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]` and I want the first list `([0,1,2])` to be separate to give `L0 = l[0]` (first list within the list is labeled as `L0`). My ideas is this:

```
for i in range(11):
  'l{}'.format(i) = l[i]
```

but the error message is this: `can't assign to function call`. I am hoping to accomplish this ultimately:

```
for i in range(11):
    list( 'l{}'.format(i)) = l[i]
```

in order to convert the string into a list. Anyone know of an way to make this work or is the idea a bust?

Comment: You surely can 'create' variables dynamically (you'd implicitly be using a dictionary). But typically, prefer to just use dictionaries instead. The error that you are facing is a basic python syntax issue. How about you read about dictionaries, come back to post a more specific question? :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is using tuple packing/unpacking

```
L = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]

L0, L1, L2 = L

print(L0)
print(L1)
print(L2)
```

result:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
```

You can create variables dynamically (However I don't think its a good idea). Dynamically creating variables should not be used where a `dict` can be used instead. If you do not know how to create dynamic variables its probably means you shouldn't. there is more than enough info in the net to look up on a quick google search to know why.

That being said here is a way to do what you want using the `dict` method.

```
L = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]

my_dict = {}
for x in range(len(L)):
    my_dict[("L%s"%(x))] = L[x]


print (my_dict)
```

The result would be:

```
{'L0': [0, 1, 2], 'L1': [3, 4, 5], 'L2': [6, 7, 8]}
```

Then all you need to do is interact with the `dict` to get anything you need from those list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec` to execute a string as if it were Python code:

```
for i in range(len(L)):
    exec('L{} = L[{}]'.format(i, i))
```

will give you variables L0, L1, L2 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
myDict = {}
for index,inner_list in enumerate(L):
  key = 'L'+str(index)
  myDict[key]=inner_list

print(myDict)
```

**RESULT**

```
{'L0': [0, 1, 2], 'L1': [3, 4, 5], 'L2': [6, 7, 8]}
```